# Given p ⇒ q, use the Fitch System to prove ¬q ⇒ ¬p.

Tags: logic

How to prove this using propositional logic operations? looks to be equvalent to !p | q

Comment: $\lambda f:P\to Q.\lambda k:\neg Q.\lambda a:P.k(f(a))$

Comment: Assume $p$; assume $\lnot q$; derive a contradiction and then derive $\lnot p$ by *negation-introduction*, discharging temporary assumption $p$.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful